# Xna converting 3D coordinate into 2D screen coordinate

Tags: 3d, xna, 2d

I know others have asked this, but I was wondering if there was a really good function to use to convert 3D points into 2D points. I tried it on my own, and it did not work. I used:

```
protected Vector2 ScreenCoords(Vector3 v, Matrix viewMatrix, Matrix projectionMatrix) 
{
    Matrix viewProj = viewMatrix * projectionMatrix;
    float w = viewProj.M14 * v.X + viewProj.M24 * v.Y + viewProj.M34 * v.Z + viewProj.M44;
    return new Vector2(
            (viewProj.M11 * v.X + viewProj.M21 * v.Y + viewProj.M31 * v.Z + viewProj.M41) / w,
            (viewProj.M12 * v.X + viewProj.M22 * v.Y + viewProj.M32 * v.Z + viewProj.M42) / w);          
}
```

Is this correct? Am I doing something wrong? I tried putting a square at the origin, and put the camera at (10, 10, 10), and pointed at (0, 0, 0), but the square did not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XNA has a built in function to handle that for you:

```
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Unproject(MyVector3Location, camera.ProjectionMatrix, camera.ViewMatrix, camera.WorldMatrix);
```

Comment: But this only gives me out a Vector3. I need to take a 3D coordinate and convert it into a 2D coordinate (Vector3 into a Vector2), if this is possible.

Comment: @cakeisajoke - it's a 2D screen coordinate, I don't know why it returns as Vector3. Just do like `Vector3 myVec = ..Unproject(..);` and `Vector2 Location = new Vector2(myVec.X, myVec.Y);`

Comment: the third variable is for storing depth, that's what the 3d engines do, use this info to sort the samples. But yes if you discard that value its 2d.